# Combining Object data Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nosql

Im Creating a scheduling app using a NoSQL database built with Angular 5.1

Here is my Sample Data

```
staff = [
    {
      name: 'John Stewart',
      updatedTimestamp: '1520221418024',
      office: 'A',
      scheduledDay: '03/25/2018',
      scheduledHours: [114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121]
    },
    {
      name: 'John Stewart',
      availableHours: [100, 101, 102, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 200, 201, 202, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 221, 222, 223]
    },
    {
      name: 'John Stewart',
      updatedTimestamp: '1520221418026',
      office: 'A',
      scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
      scheduledHours: [214, 215, 216, 217, 218]
    },
    {
      name: 'John Stewart',
      updatedTimestamp: '1520221418025',
      office: 'B',
      scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
      scheduledHours: [220, 221, 222, 223]
    },
    {
      name: 'Hal Jordan',
      availableHours: [300, 301, 302, 203, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 200, 201, 202],
    },
    {
      name: 'Hal Jordan',
      updatedTimestamp: '1520221418025',
      office: 'B',
      scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
      scheduledHours: [218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223]
    },
    {
      name: 'Guy Gardner',
      availableHours: [300, 301, 302, 203, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 200, 201, 202],
    },
    {
      name: 'Guy Gardner',
      updatedTimestamp: '1520221418025',
      office: 'CB',
      scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
      scheduledHours: [220, 221, 222, 223]
    }
]
```

100 is Sunday Midnight
101 is Sunday 1 A.M
202 is Monday 2 A.M. and so on.

I received help with this problem a few days ago, the resulting code (below) let me join my objects based on the "name".

```
combineObjects(a, b) {
  return this.staff.reduce((currentArr, nextVal) => {
    return currentArr.filter((current) => current.name === nextVal.name).length === 0
    ? [].concat(currentArr, nextVal)
    : currentArr.map((current) => current.name === nextVal.name ? Object.assign({}, current, nextVal) : current);
  }, []);
}
```

I then created a loop to run each item through my "combineObjects" function, and assigned "combineStaff" to my submit button.

```
combineStaff() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.staff.length; i++) {
      this.combineObjects(this.staff[i], this.staff[i + 1])
  }
  console.log(this.combineObjects('', ''));
  console.log('All Staff Items:', this.allStaff)
};
```

This results in each person having only one object, but it only keeps the array from the last object run through.

```
availableHours: (23) [100, 101, 102, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 200, 201, 202, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 221, 222, 223]
house:"B"
name: "John Stewart"
scheduledDay: "03/26/2018"
scheduledHours: (4) [220, 221, 222, 223]
updatedTimestamp: "1520221418025"

availableHours:(23) [300, 301, 302, 203, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 200, 201, 202]
name:"Hal Jordan"
scheduledHours: (5) [118, 119, 200, 201, 202]

availableHours: (23) [300, 301, 302, 203, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 200, 201, 202]
name: "Guy Gardner"
scheduledHours: (7) [114, 115, 116, 117, 300, 301, 302]
```

I mainly need every object's "scheduledHours" array combined into their final combined objects.

desired results:

```
availableHours: (23) [100, 101, 102, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 200, 201, 202, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 221, 222, 223]
name: "John Stewart"
scheduledHours: (17) [114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 221, 222, 223]
```

Here is a link to my demo Angular application. https://github.com/bjwhip/schedule-demo.git

Comment: make a fiddle or demo it could help someone who can solve this problem

Comment: Here is a GitHub repository with a sample Angular application.   https://github.com/bjwhip/schedule-demo.git

Comment: what i mean is a demo that generates those output like stackblitz.com, jsfiddle, codepen does.